# Query to multiple each row's cost times quantity and sum

Tags: mysql

I'm having a difficult time getting this to work. I have a table that looks like this:

```
quantity  cost
--------  ----
5         150
2         100
```

and I'd like to select a single result which should be `950`. When I use group by the entire quantities gets multiplied times the entire cost

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(quantity*cost) as sum FROM table
```